# Why is kinetic energy a scalar?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

I know that the formula for kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}$$mv^2$, and such that when we calculate it, we use the speed and not the velocity. Why is it that we use $v$ in the equation, and then proceed to ignore the direction with the velocity (we ignore any $-$ signs), and also, I thought when you multiply a vector and a scalar, $v$ and $m$ respectively, the result is a vector, not a scalar (as kinetic energy is a scalar this makes no sense to me).

Comment: That's sloppy, but convenient, notation.  More correctly:  $K=\frac{1}{2}m|v|^2$

Comment: Further to @garyp's point, for any vector $v$ the definitions $v^{2n}:=(v\cdot v)^n,\,v^{2n+1}:=v^{2n}v$ are customary.

Answer (score 12):

In the formula for the kinetic energy ($E_\text{kin}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$)
the $v^2$ is short-hand notation for the scalar
product of the velocity vector with itself:  $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}$.

Applying the [definition of the scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Definition) you get
$$\begin{align}E_\text{kin}
&=\frac{1}{2}mv^2 \\
&=\frac{1}{2}m\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}m(v_xv_x+v_yv_y+v_zv_z) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}m(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)
\end{align}$$
This result is obviously a scalar, and not a vector.

Comment: thanks for this 
in addition i guess you could think that the negatives simply "cancel" if you were to use a negative velocity anyway

Comment: @Mathguy The squares (like $v_x^2$) are always positive,
regardless of $v_x$ being positive or negstive.

Answer (score 3):

Let me just note that kinetic energy is a scalar only under Euclidean group, not under Galilean group, let alone Lorentz group.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this, please? It seems interesting, but I have little idea what it means.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 : Scalars are usually defined as quantities that are invariant under some sets of transformations. Kinetic energy is invariant under rotations and translations, but not under boosts.

Comment: I was more referring to the "Euclidean group", "Galilean group" and "Lorentz group" parts. (If you _did_ elaborate on that, it went over my head.) Are these groups as in binary operator closed over the set with associativity and identity?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 : you can look up Euclidean (Galilean, Lorentz) group, say, in Wikipedia. For example, the Euclidean group includes translations, rotations, and reflections of a Euclidean space. The binary operator is the composition of two transformation (one transformation followed by the other one), identity is the identical transformation.

Comment: Kinetic energy is only a scalar if you're only considering one frame of reference (Aristotelian physics). If you're considering multiple Newtonian inertial frames of reference, or multiple special relativity frames, kinetic energy "looks" different from the different frames – so it must be something more complicated than a simple scalar.

Comment: Is that an adequate rewording of your answer?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 : No. For example, kinetic energy does not change if you switch from one frame of reference to another using a rotation. So it is not just "one frame of reference".